# bash: How to use 'find' combined with '-exec grep' to search for an empty pair of braces

Tags: bash, grep, find, escaping, language-lawyer

I know there are other ways to accomplish this, but I'm curious, bear with me.

I would like to search a directory tree for JSON manifest files containing the exact string: `"submodules": {}`, a result from a Jenkins pipeline.

I tried several combinations and found one that finds all for me relevant locations:

```
find . -type f -name *.json -exec grep -FHm 1 '"submodules": {' {} \;
```

This works, so my problem is solved.

But now I'm just curious: I know that `{}` has a special meaning for the find command. How can I rewrite that find command to look for `"submodules": {}`? The intuitive first try would be:

```
find . -type f -name *.json -exec grep -FHm 1 '"submodules": {}' {} \;
```

But even though the shell doesn't touch the search string because of the single-quotes, the find command has no such limitation, and the command finds nothing.

I tried several ways of quoting and escaping, but couldn't find a working combination. Anyone?

Comment: It works if you replace `\;` with `+`

Comment: @anubhava It says: "find: Only one instance of {} is supported with -exec ... +"...

Comment: @General: I don't know who voted to close my question because "it violates a Stack Overflow guideline", but it would be helpful to then also add a comment explaining what is wrong in your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `egrep`/`grep -E`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec grep -EHm 1 '"submodules": \{\}' {} \;
find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec egrep -Hm 1 '"submodules": \{\}' {} \;
```

Using plain grep (without `-F`) by adding a redundant character class:

```
find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec grep -Hm 1 '"submodules": [{]}' {} \;
```

You could also create a file to run grep for you, e.g. `grep.sh`:

```
cat > grep.sh <<SH
#!/bin/sh
grep -FHm 1 '"submodules": {}' "$@"
SH
chmod +x grep.sh
```

then execute the script file via find:

```
find . -type f -name '*.json' -exec ./grep.sh {} \;
```

Comment: Good one, I didn't think of it. You let grep assume it gets a regex as input, so you can escape the braces - which grep then removes for the search - avoiding the literal combination `{}` that would have triggered `find`. I didn't think of that!
Your second suggestion will work as well, but avoiding the `{}` combination in the search string by splitting into multiple commands is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the second bracket, but you need to drop the `-F`:

```
find . -type f -name *.json -exec grep -Hm 1 '"submodules": {\}' {} \;
```

Also, using `+` instead of `\;` might run `grep` for many files at once, i.e. might be faster.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to work, since the escape for the second brace is a shell escape and doesn't work in single-quoted strings. Did you try? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: OK, I found the reason: I didn't use `-F`.